# Ionic multiple observable button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable

i have a problem with an observable on my project, i would like have a button change after click event

- list of article
- button add/remove favorite

When article is on favorite display "remove" and when is not in favorite display "add"

page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="light">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-10  style="text-align: left">
          <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo"> 
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-90  style="text-align: left">
          Actualités
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>   
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon="chevron-down-circle-outline"
      pullingText="Lacher pour raffraichir"
      refreshingSpinner="crescent"
      refreshingText="chargement...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <br>

  
  <ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts" >
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title [innerHTML]="post.title.rendered"></ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{ post.date_gmt | date }}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <div [innerHTML]="post.news_item_title"></div>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="4"><img [src]="post.picture"></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="8"><div [innerHTML]="post.excerpt.rendered"></div></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="6"><ion-button expand="full" fill="clear"  (click)="helperService.goToTendance(post.id)" text-right>Lire la suite...</ion-button></ion-col>
          <ion-col size="6"><ion-button expand="full" fill="clear"  (click)="helperService.openWebpage(post.news_item_url)" text-right>Voir la source...</ion-button></ion-col>   
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-button (click)="setFavoris(post.id)">{{favorisButtonText}}</ion-button>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Chargement actualités...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

<!--
  <ion-row>
  <ion-col width-100  style="text-align: center">
  <ion-button *ngIf="loaded === true" (click)="next()">More posts</ion-button>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 -->

</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {WordpressService} from '../services/wordpress.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {HelperService, FavorisService} from "../services/helper.service";
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss'],
  providers:[WordpressService]
})

export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
//  items: any[];
  attachs: any[];
  thumbs =  new Map();
  thumbsArr: any[];
  page: number;
  loaded:boolean;
  loading:boolean;
  posts: any = [];
  count = null;
  InAppBrowserOptions: any[];
  public expanded: any[];
  public items: any = [];

  
  favorisButtonText:string;
  favorisChangedSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public helperService: HelperService,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public wordpressService: WordpressService,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private favorisService: FavorisService,
    ) {
  }

  getKeys(map){
    return Array.from(map.keys());
  }


  doRefresh(event) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

  async loadPosts() {
    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Chargement...'
    });
    await loading.present();
 
    this.wordpressService.getTendances().subscribe(res => {
      this.count = this.wordpressService.totalPosts;
      this.posts = res;
      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
 
  loadMore(event) {
    this.page++;
 
    this.wordpressService.getTendances(this.page).subscribe(res => {
      this.posts = [...this.posts, ...res];
      event.target.complete();
 
      // Disable infinite loading when maximum reached
      if (this.page == this.wordpressService.pages) {
        event.target.disabled = true;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = false;
    this.page = 1;
    this.loadPosts();

    this.favorisChangedSubscription = this.favorisService.favorisChanged$.subscribe((favored)=>{
      this.favorisButtonText =  (favored ? "retirer favoris" : "ajout favoris");
    })

  }
  
  setFavoris(post_id):void{
    console.log(post_id);
    this.favorisService.setFavoris(post_id);
  }
 
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.favorisChangedSubscription) {
      this.favorisChangedSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FavorisService {
  private favored: boolean = false;
  private favorisSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.favored);
  favorisChanged$ = this.favorisSubject$.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setFavoris(post_id){
    this.favored = !this.favored;
    this.favorisSubject$.next(this.favored);
  }

}
```

WHen i click on the button, it's change for all buttons, i think, i must have an observable by article , someone can help me?

Comment: You only have one favored variable, every article is sharing it. Does this service do anything else? It doesn't even use the post_id that you are passing it. From what you have posted, I think you need a PostComponent that manages its own favorite state on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through your objects to display here:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts" >
```

Because of this you have everything you need, likely without observables. What I would recommend:

on this posts array, is it possible to add a field to use where you currently have `{{favorisButtonText}}`? maybe something like `{{post.buttonText}}`, and then on click you can call a method via:

```
(click)="setFavoris(post.id)
...
ts:
setFavoris(post) {
 post.buttonText =  (post.buttonText === "retirer favoris" ? "ajout favoris" : "retirer favoris");
}
```

Because the post object is an array and javascript treats these by reference this should cause the changes to show immediately for the element you clicked upon.

Observables are awesome, but are more useful in situations where you need to share a common object across multiple components.

Hopefully this is helpful, good luck!

PS:
If you need to, you can always store the posts button text in way that is separate to the posts array you recieve (if you don't want to alter the payload or want it to persist in a service).

You can create a simple associative object, where each property has a key/value pair for the post.id and button text.
you could do something like:

```
myservice:
postButtonTexts: any;

myComponent:
onPostLoad() {
   this.getposts.subscribe(res => {
       if(!myService.postButtonTexts) {
           myService.postButtonTexts = {};
          for(cost post of res.posts) {
             myService.postButtonTexts[post.id] = 'Initial button Text';
          }
        }
    }
```

and then in the template you can put the buttonText as
`{{myService.postButtonTexts[post.id]}}`

Answer (score 0):

thank a lot for you help it will be usefull and if i can help someme

in myservice

```
  setFavoris(event,post_id):void{
    if(event.target.value){
      this.wordpressService.addFavorites(this.getUser().user_id,post_id).subscribe(res => {
        event.target.innerHTML = "retier favoris";
      });    
    }else{     
      this.wordpressService.removeFavorites(this.getUser().user_id,post_id).subscribe(res => {
        event.target.innerHTML = "ajouter favoris";
      });      
    }
    event.target.value = !event.target.value;
  }
```

page.html

```
<ion-button [expand]="" [value]="post.favorisButton" (click)="helperService.setFavoris($event,post.id)"><ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>{{post.favorisButtonText}}</ion-button>
```

page.ts

```
async loadPosts() {
    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Chargement...'
    });
    await loading.present();
 
    this.wordpressService.getTendances().subscribe(res => {
      this.count = this.wordpressService.totalPosts;

      let index = 0;
      let favored;
      for (let post of res) {
        //console.log(index,data[index]['content']['rendered']);
       favored = this.helperService.inArray(post.id,this.favoris.favorites);
       res[index]['favorisButtonText']= (favored ? "retirer favoris" : "ajouter favoris");
       res[index]['favorisButton']= (favored ? false: true);
       index++;
      }

      this.posts = res;

      loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

it's work fine, don't know if it's the best way